# Language loading and back button issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I made a multi-lang app for contents. In the backend, you create content, and show it in a frontend page. I have an issue with the back button (I think its a cache issue) following the next steps:

1. You click in a content link and access to the content view.
2. In the current content view (with the current language), you click to
   switch language.
3. It redirects you to home with the new language.
4. When you press back button, it sends you to the previus content (in
   the previus language).

A consideration:
- If I clear the browser cache between the steps 2-3, it works fine.

Here is the code:

**In the language switcher controller**

```
    $this->lang_array = $this->Language_model->getLangsArray();

    if(!isset($this->session->lang)){
        if(array_key_exists($this->uri->segment(1), $this->lang_array)){
            $this->session->lang = $this->uri->segment(1);
        }else{
            $this->session->lang = 'es';
        }
    }

    if(isset($this->session->lang)){
        if(array_key_exists($this->uri->segment(1), $this->lang_array) && $this->uri->segment(1) != $this->session->lang){
            $this->session->lang = $this->uri->segment(1);
        }
    }

    $this->lang->load($this->lang_array[$this->session->lang], $this->lang_array[$this->session->lang]);
```

**To return the view with content, in the contents controller:**

```
    $content = $this->db->get_where('contents', array('slug' => $slug), 1)->result();
    if(count($content)){
        $content = $content[0];

        $this->view('content_view', $content));
    }else{
        return array();
    }
```

Comment: I am really curious as to how you manage to clear the browser cache between steps 2 and 3. Also, this seems like an XY issue. You should be trying to keep your user on the current page after language switch rather than trying to defeat browser behavior.

Comment: @coderodour I use clear browser cache in the browser, just to see if It could be a cache issue. Im not interested in keeping the user in the current page, since the content for one language could be not available in another language, so I prefer to be redirect the user to the home page when the language is switched. When the user is redirected, he can click the "back" button, and he/she gets access to the previus content in the previus language, which is what I want to prevent.